# Getting http/https protocols to match with <iframe> for maps.google.com

Tags: javascript, http, google-maps, https, protocols

I am trying to use an `<iframe>` include of a google map, however the console is throwing several errors due to a mismatch, but there is no apparent mismatch, so I'm assuming it must be a function/process on the  side of google maps.

Specifically with maps.google.com, there appears to be a change to the script for the iframe, according to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/xX9syA1k-oE).

The errors in the console is this: ( I am getting at least 30 errors on page load )

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.developer.host.com/ from
frame with URL https://maps.google.com/maps/msmsa=0&msid=
212043342089249462794.00048cfeb10fb9d85b995&ie=UTF8&t=
m&ll=35.234403,-80.822296&spn=0.392595,0.137329&z=10&output=embed. 

The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being
accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.
```

Since my site is http and NOT https, and the map url is http, why is the mismatch occuring, and how do I fix this to make them match?

Comment: it is not your fault it's a google bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43173

Comment: Can you show us the exact embedding code (HTML markup)?

Comment: <iframe width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=212043342089249462794.00048cfeb10fb9d85b995&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=35.234403,-80.822296&amp;spn=0.392595,0.137329&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>View <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=212043342089249462794.00048cfeb10fb9d85b995&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=35.234403,-80.822296&amp;spn=0.392595,0.137329&amp;z=10&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Charlotte</a> in a larger map</small>

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The following jsFiddle shows the code I have tested with: http://jsfiddle.net/YNwGL/
It loads without any warning in Chrome, FF and IE9.
I guess Google has solved the issue.

Comment: chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 (latest build) still has the issue...   FF did not show issues, and I dont have IE on the mac(d-oh) @Jpsy

Comment: Is it possible that this is Mac related? I don't have this issue with Chrome 24 on Windows 7 64.

Comment: @Jpsy if you don't mind, take a look here https://www.evernote.com/shard/s55/sh/0ddc8d59-1337-4b50-95de-d5e56efc5e38/a9e44b72ab6c26f743751e2f519030c7

Comment: Sorry Nathan, you are FULLY right! I get the same JS errors when I open up the Chrome console. I did not look there before because I have a Chrome plugin that tells me about JS errors right within the address bar, but it did not fire. It obviously does not catch errors that occur in an iFrame document.

Comment: @Jpsy   Curious, what extension do you use that fires console errors in the address bar?

Comment: @chrisFrisina: it is called _JavaScript Errors Notifier_. See here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd

Answer (score 16):

This really is a bug of the embeddable HTML code, created by the standalone Google Maps page ([maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) -> click on link chain button to get the iframe based HTML code).
As said by aSeptik in the comments to your question, the corresponding bug report [can be found here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43173).

You can avoid that bug if you embed a Google Map using the Maps API. It does make no difference if you use the Maps API directly in your page or within an embedded iframe - both ways work fine.

Here is [an example](http://www.renect.de/kontakt.php) of some other map where I have used the Maps API within an iframe.

And here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/fBdvG/) of **your own map** using the Maps API - embedded right within the page.

The additional code needed for the Maps API is actually very small:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function(){
            var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.201867,-80.836029),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

            var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&t=m&authuser=0&msa=0&output=kml&msid=212043342089249462794.00048cfeb10fb9d85b995');
            kmlLayer.setMap(gMap);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
```

I have used jQuery here for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the attribute `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the `</iframe>` solves the issue:

Example:

```html
<iframe
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d10005.660822865373!2d6.3855055!3d51.1745698!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xbc2d05dc3af26862!2sBORUSSIA-PARK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1448289882279"
        width="400"
        height="300"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cant say about the bug that aSeptik mentioned, but if you want to avoid the http/https issue simply dont write it in the URL.

Eg: Instead of writing 'http://maps.google.com' which will result in the warning you received, write '//maps.google.com', this will automatically take the current sessions scheme (http/https) and make the API call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Nor does it solve the problem to prepend the Gmaps call with ``http://``.