# jquery - if(thing.is(:hover)) {do something}

Tags: jquery

I can't get this to work.  On mouseover, show a div. On mouseleave, if still over shown element continue to show that element, else fade out the element.

```
$('#list_cont').on('mouseenter', '.show_map', function() {
    $(this).next('.map_cont').fadeIn(800);
}).on('mouseleave', '.show_map', function() {
    var mapcont = $(this).next('.map_cont');
    if (mapcont.is(':hover')) {
        mapcont.show();
    } else {
        $(this).next('.map_cont').delay(600).fadeOut(800);
    }
});​
```

Problem is, the element never leaves.  Example [here](http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=list).  Hover the map icon.

Comment: Can you post some markup or jsfiddle example?

Comment: So when should the element be faded out?

Comment: How could a mouseout event fire when the mouse is still over it?

Comment: have you debugged by sticking alert() calls in the code to see when and where your code is executed? I am unfamiliar with the jQuery stacking of 'on' event handlers like this. Could you attach the handlers iteratively and see if that works?

Comment: It's when mouseleave on the element that shows another element.  If mouse is on shown element, do nothing.  If mouseleave element that triggers `.fadeIn` but is not on element that was shown, then `.fadeOut`

Comment: The sheer number of JavaScript errors on your site are overwhelming my console. You need to fix those first.

Comment: Your code works fine -- when you mouse off the icon onto the background page, the map fades. Perhaps you want to add a second event handler when a user mouses off the map?

Comment: @Blazemonger: check this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555261/getting-http-https-protocols-to-match-with-iframe-for-maps-google-com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this. Use event handlers on both the icon and the map, fading out only when the mouse leaves both elements:

```
$('#list_cont').on('mouseenter', '.show_map', function() {
    $(this).next('.map_cont').stop().fadeIn(800);
}).on('mouseleave', '.show_map', function() {
    if (!$(this).next('.map_cont').is(':hover')) {
        $(this).next('.map_cont').delay(600).stop().fadeOut(800);
    }
});

$('#list_cont').on('mouseenter', '.show_map', function() {
    $(this).stop().show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.map_cont', function() {
    $(this).delay(600).stop().fadeOut(800);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JV89J/1/